# How to ensure all tasks have been executed and query the final results

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, .net-4.0, task

I'm using Tasks to perform a computation intensive operation. **PerformCalculation** method. The main parent task uses Task factory to create three child tasks and starts execution. Each child task shall return 
a `List<Dictionary<int,double>>`

```
List<double> paramList = new List<double>{ 2, 2.5, 3};

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task parent = new Task(() =>
{
    var tf = new TaskFactory<List<Dictionary<int, double>>>(cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);

    var childTasks = new[] {
        tf.StartNew(() => PerformCalculation(cts.Token, paramList[0],Task.CurrentId)),
        tf.StartNew(() => PerformCalculation(cts.Token, paramList[1],Task.CurrentId)),
        tf.StartNew(() => PerformCalculation(cts.Token, paramList[2],Task.CurrentId)) //3rd entry
        };
```

The results of child tasks upon successful execution shall be in the form of a `List<Dictionary<int, double>>`.

Now my requirement is to write a lambda expression that would query the results from all of the child tasks once they are finished executing and populate in another list

i.e. list of list (`List<List<Dictionary<int, double>>>`)

```
// When all children are done, get the value returned from the
// non-faulting/canceled tasks. 
tf.ContinueWhenAll(childTasks, completedTasks => 
                   completedTasks
                   .Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)**??Need HELP HERE ???**),CancellationToken.None)
,TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll side step the question a bit because all these APIs are essentially obsolete (or at least not suitable for "mainstream" scenarios). This is actually fairly easy:

```
var childTasks = new[] {
    Task.Run(() => PerformCalculation(cts.Token, paramList[0],Task.CurrentId)),
    Task.Run(() => PerformCalculation(cts.Token, paramList[1],Task.CurrentId)),
    Task.Run(() => PerformCalculation(cts.Token, paramList[2],Task.CurrentId)),
    };

var results = Task.WhenAll(childTasks).Result;
```

`TaskFactory` is a fairly esoteric type that I have never seen used in the wild. Attached child tasks should be avoided since they add non-obvious dependencies. None of these are mistakes but they are smells.

Comment: I cannot use await, as my limitation is that I have to use .NET 4.0

Comment: You can use await with 4.0 but I have edited that out. In any case you might notice that the use of await is non-essential to this answer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: The Task.Run() is not available in .NET 4.0, However I had to use Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Dictionary<int,double>>>(() => PerformCalculation(cts.Token, paramList[0],Task.CurrentId)). Also any ideas what would be the alternative for Task.WhenAll(childTasks).Result

Comment: Right... these are not available in 4.0 either... Try Task.WaitAll followed by childTasks.Select(t => t.Result) to extract the results. That would be the "need help" line from your query. No need to check the status.